# TSQL Select Sorted Columns with Prev Current Next

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, sorting

I have a table with these columns:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|PrevStation|CurrentStation|NextStation|
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|-          |A             |B          |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|A          |B             |C          |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|B          |C             |D          |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|C          |D             |E          |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|D          |F             |-          |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

Now I want represent to a view by:

```
+---------------+
|ClosestStations|
+---------------+
|A              |
+---------------+
|B              |
+---------------+
|C              |
+---------------+
|D              |
+---------------+
|E              |
+---------------+
|F              |
+---------------+
```

**Notice: I want sorted rows with contract of first table **

What do you think about a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Select [CLoseStation] from
(
   select PrevStation AS [CLoseStation],PrevStation ,NextStation,CurrentStation
   From T
   Union
   Select NextStation AS [CLoseStation],PrevStation ,NextStation,CurrentStation
   From T
   union
   Select CurrentStation AS [CLoseStation],PrevStation ,NextStation,CurrentStation
   From T
) AS S Order By PrevStation ,NextStation,CurrentStation ASC
```

Comment: so make a change in your question too

Comment: @Arash I have updated solution as you said. Please check it now

Comment: Thanks a lot, I test query on real data but yet,i dont have a valid table, I think your query is partially correct OR my real data is not reliable!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [recursive query](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but this will get pretty inefficient if you have a long linked list

```
use tempdb
go

create table #stations (prev char, [current] char)

INSERT INTO #stations 
values (null, 'A'),
    ('A', 'B'),
    ('B', 'C'),
    ('C', 'D'),
    ('D', 'E'),
    ('E', 'F');

with rec (this, level)
AS (
    SELECT [current], 0 FROM #stations where prev is null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [current], rl.level + 1
    FROM #stations sc
    INNER JOIN rec rl ON sc.prev = rl.this
)
SELECT *
FROM rec
ORDER BY level asc;

DROP TABLE #stations;

-- Produces
--this level
------ -----------
--A    0
--B    1
--C    2
--D    3
--E    4
--F    5
```

Since this linked-list style table is so hard to query, you may wish to translate it to an ordered table.  Using a loop will avoid running into limits imposed by `MAXRECURSION`:

```
use tempdb
go

CREATE TABLE #stations (prev char, [current] char)

INSERT INTO #stations 
values (null, 'A'),
    ('A', 'B'),
    ('B', 'C'),
    ('C', 'D'),
    ('D', 'E'),
    ('E', 'F');

CREATE TABLE #stationPositions (station char, sequence int)

DECLARE @seq int = 0,
    @station char

SELECT TOP(1) @Station = [current]
FROM #stations
WHERE prev is null

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #stationPositions (station, sequence)
    VALUES (@station, @seq)

    SELECT TOP(1) @station = [current]
    FROM #stations
    WHERE prev = @station

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK

    SET @seq = @seq + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #stationPositions

DROP TABLE #stations;
DROP TABLE #stationPositions;

-- Results:
--station sequence
--------- -----------
--A       0
--B       1
--C       2
--D       3
--E       4
--F       5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `union` query:

```
select station
from ((select PrevStation as station
       from t
      ) union
      (select NextStation
       from t
      ) union
      (select CurrentStation
       from t
      )
     ) t
where station is not null
order by station;
```

Comment: I am need to be sorted rows. A B C D =>